# RAID5 Arrary disappeard with no HW or SW changes made

Tags: debian, mount, mdadm, raid5

I have a R-Pi running XBMC (Linux CaribNAS 3.10.24 #2 PREEMPT Mon Dec 23 05:18:12 UTC 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux) with a 3 disk raid 5 array that has been working up till yesterday when is stopped running overnight and now will now not start, I have a lot of data that is not backed up so would like to recover without data loss if poss.

I have noticed that mdadm --examine --scan shows two /dev/md/0 arrays, only the second one is correct, but I can't get rid of the first, but I don't think this is the cause but would like to tidy things up.

```
 dmesg |grep md:
 md: md0 stopped.
 md: sdc1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
 md: md_import_device returned -22
 md: sdd1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
 md: md_import_device returned -22
 md: sdb1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
 md: md_import_device returned -22


 mdadm -D /dev/md0
 mdadm: md device /dev/md0 does not appear to be active.


 mdadm --examine --scan
 ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=c20f8d11:b81ae9b6:1b318343:ed35987e name=raspbmc:0
 ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=8ec7d307:b5609dfd:caea7099:a9d8201c name=CaribNAS:0


 cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
 DEVICE partitions
 HOMEHOST CaribNAS
 MAILADDR CaribNAS@gmail.com
 ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 Name=CaribNAS:0 UUID=8ec7d307:b5609dfd:caea7099:a9d8201c

 cat /etc/fstab
 proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
 devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
 /dev/sda1 / ext4 defaults 0 0
 /dev/sda2 /temp ext4 defaults 0 0
 /dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot vfat defaults,noatime 0 0
 #/dev/mmcblk0p2 / f2fs defaults,noatime 0 0
 /dev/md0 /RAID5 auto defaults 0 3


 cat /proc/mdstat
 Personalities :
 unused devices: <none>

 mdadm --stop /dev/md0
 mdadm: stopped /dev/md0

 mdadm --assemble --scan -v
 mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
 mdadm: /dev/sdd has wrong uuid.
 mdadm: /dev/sdc has wrong uuid.
 mdadm: /dev/sdb has wrong uuid.
 mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda2
 mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda1
 mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
 mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p2
 mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p1
 mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/mmcblk0
 mdadm: /dev/sdd1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
 mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
 mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
 mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdc1 to /dev/md0: Invalid argument
 mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdd1 to /dev/md0: Invalid argument
 mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdb1 to /dev/md0: Invalid argument
 mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md0: Invalid argument

 mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bcd]1
 mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bcd]1
 /dev/sdb1:
 Magic : a92b4efc
 Version : 1.2
 Feature Map : 0x0
 Array UUID : 8ec7d307:b5609dfd:caea7099:a9d8201c
 Name : CaribNAS:0 (local to host CaribNAS)
 Creation Time : Thu Jan 16 02:44:56 2014
 Raid Level : raid5
 Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 1953260975 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
 Array Size : 1953260544 (1862.77 GiB 2000.14 GB)
 Used Dev Size : 1953260544 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
 Data Offset : 262144 sectors
 Super Offset : 8 sectors
 State : clean
 Device UUID : 8d6ee8dc:1d62a673:74189894:14192b98

 Update Time : Sat Mar 15 15:46:41 2014
 Checksum : 2cd2a9ae - correct
 Events : 345

 Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 512K

 Device Role : Active device 0
 Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
 /dev/sdc1:
 Magic : a92b4efc
 Version : 1.2
 Feature Map : 0x0
 Array UUID : 8ec7d307:b5609dfd:caea7099:a9d8201c
 Name : CaribNAS:0 (local to host CaribNAS)
 Creation Time : Thu Jan 16 02:44:56 2014
 Raid Level : raid5
 Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 1953260975 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
 Array Size : 1953260544 (1862.77 GiB 2000.14 GB)
 Used Dev Size : 1953260544 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
 Data Offset : 262144 sectors
 Super Offset : 8 sectors
 State : clean
 Device UUID : 2f8065d8:ff3a060d:4883c25f:12f543f7

 Update Time : Sat Mar 15 15:46:41 2014
 Checksum : ebf2db04 - correct
 Events : 345

 Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 512K

 Device Role : Active device 1
 Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
 /dev/sdd1:
 Magic : a92b4efc
 Version : 1.2
 Feature Map : 0x0
 Array UUID : 8ec7d307:b5609dfd:caea7099:a9d8201c
 Name : CaribNAS:0 (local to host CaribNAS)
 Creation Time : Thu Jan 16 02:44:56 2014
 Raid Level : raid5
 Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 1953260975 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
 Array Size : 1953260544 (1862.77 GiB 2000.14 GB)
 Used Dev Size : 1953260544 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
 Data Offset : 262144 sectors
 Super Offset : 8 sectors
 State : clean
 Device UUID : 38c6ce39:0ad01a8c:d188672b:4b06661f

 Update Time : Sat Mar 15 15:46:41 2014
 Checksum : c037ccdb - correct
 Events : 345

 Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 512K

 Device Role : Active device 2
 Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```